# navigate across history stacks ionic ion-tabs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I currently have a problem where I have a application that has 4 ion tabs of which they each have their own history stack. I am now having a problem where i navigate from say tab A => B, tab B is moved to inner page of tab B, but there is no way of navigating back and resetting the history on tab B so that when I go back to tab A I can reset tab B's history to the root of tab B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I get you right, do you want to clear the navigation stack within a tab when changing tabs? So have a look at the following approach:

`<ion tab>` has a callback when deselecting. You can use this to call a function in your controller which clears the history. So your html page looks for example like this:

```
<ion-tab title="xyz" href="#/tab/whatever" on-deselect="clearHistory()">
   ...
</ion-tab>
```

And in your controller define the following coresponding function:

```
.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $ionicHistory) {
   $scope.clearHistory = function() {
      $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
   }
})
```

This clears this navigation stack of the current tab before leaving. I tested it with the ionic tabs starter templates and it worked for me.

I hope this was your issue. If not, leave me a comment and I will look again into it.

Comment: thanks for the response, unfortunately that's not quite what i want, but what you have said will be useful anyway. ATM i am opening a modal on tab A linking to tab B, i then need to get back to tab A and clear history on tab B. thanks. this will clear history i guess but not get me back to tab A.

Comment: To navigate to another tab just use `$ionicTabsDelegate.select(index)`.

Comment: thank you very much, been scratching my head over this all day. will solve my issue thanks.

Comment: just as an added extra here, im using a main controller on an abstract state called app controller, in order to get to nested view controllers simply broadcast a tab deselect using $scope.$broadcast('tabDeselect'); listen for that in the child controller then fire the history reset. for a little more after that you can create a resolve function that captures the previous state on the state config section, then when listening for the broadcast you can check the state you came from before destroying the history.

Comment: I have found this very annoying as well while navigating between tabs. The solution doesn't fully satisfy me and I ended up duplicating the route state for the internal tab view for each tab that would potentially navigate to it. Not an elegant solution but do the job better imo.